# In Multiplayer how do you call in an Artillery or Air Strike?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

I know that in previous battlefield games you could call in artillery strikes.

Are artillery/air strikes still possible and how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No artillery or air strike in BFBC2. You'll have to only rely on the guys who are there! :)

But you can also rely on your friends in helicopters and tanks so, pretty much more devastating than an artillery strike sometimes! :)

Comment: What about the mortar strike?

Comment: Right, but the mortar strike is just a gadget for the Recon class. It's not like the air/artillery strike of other games, available to all players when on a killing frenzy.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official artillery strike in Bad Company 2, but the mortar strike is a weaker version of the same thing.  The mortar strike which as LudoMC says is a gadget that unlocks for the Recon class after you've gained enough points.